# Parse error on double quotes (but there's no error on local server)

Tags: php

So I have the following function on my code:

```
/* returns a random string */
function randStr($length = 32, $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyvwzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYVWZ!@#$%&*()_-+=") {
//function randStr($length, $chars) {
    $validCharNumber = strlen($chars);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $str .= $chars[rand(0, $validCharNumber - 1)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

it was working ok on my local server and some other development server that we used. But on the final server, I keep getting the following message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

I searched on google but I couldnt get precise results because I can't use quotes to be more accurate when I'm searching about quotes.

I'm also getting the same error message on this block of code

```
"last_update" => Array("display" => "return toDate('$1', 'd/m/Y H:i:s');")
```

Where's the error? Did I miss any kind of configuration for double quotes or something?

Comment: please try single quotation 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyvwzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYVWZ!@#$%&*()_-+='

Comment: I tried, and it worked, but I would've to do that on the whole project. if double quotes are working on my local server, why aren't they working on air?

Comment: may be your server not support because some times has critical situation like this \ or /

Comment: There _is_ no syntax error in the code you have shown, and there is also no configuration option that would influence that. Most likely your file just got messed up when it was uploaded to the server, and so does now not actually contain what you _think_ it would.

Comment: The file is ok. I know there is no error because I've always used this function. But like sectus said, it must be a version issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's php version issue. You could check your code for php versions compatibilities with online tools which allow to run code on different versions.

For example: http://3v4l.org/60NfG

Deal in '$' inside double quoted string in function argument.

http://3v4l.org/lvm9I

Comment: No error at all, just a version issue like you said. Anyway I had to replace some of my classes. I'll take it as an warning to know where to use single and double quotes plus $. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I only got this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: str in D:\wamp\www\index.php on line 7

Fixed it by adding `$str ='';` before for loop. Everything else works fine.

My PHP Version is 5.4.12